# Tool for clearing build directories (different programming languages/frameworks)

Tags: files, compiling

Aside from writing own scripts, is there some kind of CLI tool that can scan target folders or volumes and delete build artifacts or recreatable dependencies with support for different programming languages/frameworks?

For example I want to be able to run such a tool in a directory where I keep source code for different programming projects. This tool would delete build ephemereal artifacts, like `node_modules` for NodeJS projects and such.

I have tried googling but did not find anything.

Comment: Could you be more specific? [edit your question] Presumably you refer to particular build from source systems?

Comment: I updated my question